# Arduino car parking program help

Tags: arduino-uno

[image]

Here is a program and circuit diagram of an Arduino-based car parking (copy pasted from http://www.arduining.com/2012/10/13/arduino-parking-lot-filled/ ) I want to replace the Exit and End switch with IR sensor or ultrasonic sensor.

```cpp
/*ParkingL02.pde
  Arduining.com 08 JUL 2012
  Code used in the production of the Youtube material.
*/
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo; // create servo object to control a servo
#define ServoM 12 //Connected to the servo motor.
#define Bright 11 //servo library disable PWM on pins 9 and 10.
#define Exit 9 //Pin connected to the EXIT button.
#define In 8 //Pin connected to the IN button.
#define BarLow 177 //Low position of the barrier.
#define BarUp 95 //Up position of the barrier.
#define CAPACITY 8 //Capacity of the parking lot.
#define INTEN 80 //Display intensity %
//Pins conections to segments (cathodes).
#define segA 0
#define segB 1
#define segC 2
#define segD 3
#define segE 4
#define segF 5
#define segG 6

int SensorIn(void);     // declare the sensor function for entering autos

//Array with the segments to represent the decimal numbers (0-9).
byte segments[10] = {
  // pgfedcba <--- segments
  B00111111, // number 0
  B00000110, // number 1
  B01011011, // number 2
  B01001111, // number 3
  B01100110, // number 4
  B01101101, // number 5
  B01111101, // number 6
  B00000111, // number 7
  B01111111, // number 8
  B01101111 // number 9
};

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(ServoM); // attaches the servo.

  pinMode(Exit, INPUT); // set "EXIT" button pin to input
  pinMode(In, INPUT); // set "IN" button pin to input

  digitalWrite(Exit, HIGH); // Connect Pull-Up resistor.
  digitalWrite(In, HIGH); // Connect Pull-Up resistor.

  pinMode(segA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segF, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Bright, OUTPUT);

  analogWrite(Bright, 255 * INTEN / 100);
  myservo.write(BarLow); //Barrier in the low position
  // delay(1000);
}

int Available = 9; // Number of places available.

void loop() {
  Display(Available);
  if ( SensorIn() == 0 )
  {
    if (Available != 0) {
      Available--;
      myservo.write(BarUp);
      delay(3000);
      myservo.write(BarLow);
    }
  }
  if (digitalRead(Exit) == 0)
  {
    if (Available != CAPACITY) {
      Available++;
      myservo.write(BarUp);
      delay(3000);
      myservo.write(BarLow);
    }
  }
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------
  Put the segments according to the number.
  --------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void Display(int number) {
  byte segs = ~segments[number]; //"~" is used for commom anode.
  digitalWrite(segA, bitRead(segs, 0) );
  digitalWrite(segB, bitRead(segs, 1) );
  digitalWrite(segC, bitRead(segs, 2) );
  digitalWrite(segD, bitRead(segs, 3) );
  digitalWrite(segE, bitRead(segs, 4) );
  digitalWrite(segF, bitRead(segs, 5) );
  digitalWrite(segG, bitRead(segs, 6) );
}


// We've moved the "sensor code" for entering autos to this function
// For now, the "In-sensor" is just a push-button.
int SensorIn(void) {
  return ( digitalRead(In) );
}
```

Comment: It might help if you format your code.

Comment: Theoretically, an IR sensor could/would work exactly the same as an button (code wise).

Comment: I want circuit with connection of IR Sensor

Comment: i need this code but i have and lcd i'm doing the same project with two IR sensors so please if anyone have done it with lcd i will be thankfull i have to show it next week please help

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I'd approach it this way:

- Move each button read (digitalRead(xxx)) into its own routine.
- Get everything to work, still using the buttons.
- Write a separate sketch for whatever sensor or sensors you're going to use. All it needs to do is light an LED so you can be sure when it is detecting and when it isn't.
- Now replace the contents of each of the new button routines (from step 1) with the sensor code you just wrote. Your routines should return the *same values* for sensor detection that they returned for button detection. You shouldn't need to change any other part of your original code.
- Fix any bugs you made in the step above, and you're done.

Update:

I've just indented your code (above) and made one of the changes I suggested. You'll see that I made a new function called SensorIn() and put the code to read the "In" button there. Do the same thing for the "Exit" button.

Then, using a new sketch, learn to write code for whatever kind of sensor you want to use for entering autos. When that works, copy it into this sketches 'SensorIn()' function, replacing the line that reads the push button. Get this much working.

Then do the same thing, write a new sketch for the exit sensor until you can make that work reliably, too. Of course, if you choose to use the same kind of sensor for Exit as you used for In, you can just re-use the same code. Get this sketch working again.

Now you should have a sketch, just like your pushbutton sketch, but one that uses two real sensors instead of buttons.

Comment: Can u rewrite the code for me ..  and paste for me plzz... I'm kinda nooob..N  I'm getting confused... Writing separate code for ultrasonic sensor.. and calling in place of button .  Causing more error 

Comment: @ManlamKonyakArolim If you don't know how to do that ...

Comment: The coding and project is completed ..its an old question :) thank you anyway